# ADALiOS:Cannot add a new item in the keychain / O365-iOS-Connect-Swift

Tags: ios, office365, adal

I am currently working on an iOS-App that connects to Office365, with the **target of iOS7**. The following pods are used:

```
pod 'ADALiOS', '~> 1.2.1'
pod 'Office365/Outlook', '= 0.9.1'
pod 'Office365/Discovery', '= 0.9.1'
```

When I run it in the simulator all works fine. When I run it on the device, I get a 'Cannot add a new item in the keychain' error.

I also tried the **Shared keychain** capability, but that didn't change anything.

This is the error message, **it even occurs when I run the O365-iOS-Connect-Swift sample** from Github:

> 2015-06-16 20:44:58.758 O365-iOS-Connect-Swift[574:128561]
>   -[ADAuthenticationBroker webAuthenticationDidCompleteWithURL:][379][main]  2015-06-16
>   20:44:59.586 O365-iOS-Connect-Swift[574:128676] ADALiOS [2015-06-16
>   18:44:59 - EEAB650A-32FE-4589-925D-EB9797B89E08] ERROR: Error raised:
>   11. Additional Information: Domain: ADAuthenticationErrorDomain ProtocolCode:(null) Details:Cannot add a new item in the keychain.
>   Error code: -25243.

Could someone from the ADALiOS team help me please? Any hint is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to enable keychain sharing and  add com.microsoft.adalcache to your app entitlements.

Comment: Great that is the solution, thanks a lot!
BTW, it would certainly be much helpful to other developers if you guys could include it in the docs on github, or didn't I see it there?

Comment: We will add it. Thanks. If this worked for you then can you accept this as the answer please?

Comment: Just came across this very issue (on the same day - weird). Also would appreciate it being added to the github docs. Thanks.